# how do I assign a new function to descriptor.value?

Tags: typescript, decorator

I'm trying to implement a logging decorator in typescript, but I can reassign descriptor.value

I'm compiling with target: "es6" and with experimentalDecorators and emitDecoratorMetadata enabled
I added the MethodDecorator and the generic signature but I can't re assign a value to the descriptor

```
export function log(configs: any): MethodDecorator {
   return <T>(target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<T>): TypedPropertyDescriptor<T> | void => {
    debugger;
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = (...args: any): any => {
      console.log('ENTRY ');
      console.dir(args);
      const ret = originalMethod.apply(target, args);
      console.log('EXIT ');
      console.dir(ret);
      return ret
    }
    return descriptor;
  }
}
```

this should allow me to create logging wrapper function
but in the line

descriptor.value = (...args: any): any => {

I get this error :

Type '(...args: any) => any' is not assignable to type 'T'.ts(2322)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

Define your `descriptor` as `PropertyDescriptor` instead of `TypedPropertyDescriptor<T>`.

```
(target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => { 
   /* ... */
}
```

**Explanation**

Since your decorator is not created with any specific method in mind, it's not possible to determine what `T` in `TypedPropertyDescriptor<T>` is in advance. And if we don't know what `T` is, we cannot override it, because there is no guarantee our override will be of the same type as `T`. Any attempt to write to `descriptor.value` will raise an error.

The definition for `PropertyDescriptor`, on the other hand, is more relaxed and suitable for a generic-purpose generator like the one you are creating.